# как вынести в отдельный чанк библиотеку

Tags: webpack

У меня в проекте есть библиотека, которая весит очень много.

Я не буду углублятся почему я хочу именно такой вариант подключения, но поверьте это оправдано.

Подключена она через `import QWE from 'qwe'`
есть в проекте условно `chunk1` и `chunk2`.
Библиотека `qwe` импортируется в оба чанка, изза чего библиотека попадает в оба чанка.

Возможности подключить библиотеку во всех местах проекта через *(асинхронный)*`import('qwe')` нет.

Вынести `qwe` в externals тоже нельзя.

Можно ли как то добится эфекта как от externals, когда во всех местах проекта библиотека изолируется и не попадает ни в какой чанк, даже если подключена через синхронный `import`, но что б при этом она была в отдельном чанке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте эту конфигурацию, учтите, что свойство `optimization` доступно только в версии `webpack >= 4`, если версия `webpack < 4` - используйте `CommonsChunkPlugin`, мы указываем `runtimeChunk: true`, для того, чтобы создать отдельный чанк, `splitChunks` ищет модули, которые совместно используются несколькими модулями и создает отдельный чанк, чтобы уменьшить дублирование + кеширует этот чанк, чтобы не ребилдить каждый раз при изменении кода.

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,

    entry: {
        vendor: ['название вашей библиотеки'],
        app: 'путь к главному файлу'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        pathinfo: true
    },

    target: 'web',

    mode: 'development',

    module: {
        rules: [...Ваши лоадеры]
    },

    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: true,
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    name: 'vendor',
                    test: 'vendor',
                    enforce: true
                }
            }
        }
   }
};
```